# DNS not working?

Tags: dns

I just wanted to start by warning you I’m about as amateur as it gets but if you’re still willing to help me out I would be so grateful!

Ok, so as the situation stands I finished setting up my new network setup (consisting of: EdgeRouterX, UAP lite and a Vigor 120 Modem, so I could ditch the Homehub that is provided by my isp.). All was fine for roughly 24hrs, but then after turning my PC on I could not connect to the internet on despite being able to access the EdgeRouterX’s Web Interface and being able to browse the web, game, stream, etc on other devices (such as a PS4 and an iPhone) and I’m still able to that now.

So on my PC I sometimes get the little yellow warning ‘!’ Where it shows my connection and sometimes it shows it is fine. The things I have tried are: pinging 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4 (successful), pinging www.google.co.uk (unsuccessful), enabling/disabling firewall (unsuccessful), setting my DNS to 8.8.8.8, running windows diagnostics which told me I was having a DNS issue, doing ipconfig /flushdns, etc and some other things to which did not work.

I could really do with internet on that PC so the sooner I get it solved the better, please ask for anymore info that you need and any help is much appreciated!

Thanks guys!

Comment: To be honest, I think something like this requires an interactive debugging session, and stackexchange may not be the best place to ask. Have you tried IRC channels (or even chat.stackexchange.com) to see if someone can help you work through it?

Comment: No I haven’t, thanks for the suggestion will try now.

Comment: No one responds on them, seems pretty pointless.

Answer (score 0):

#### after turning my PC on I could not connect to the internet

Try reinitialising the network states. Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: Ok I have just run all of these commands and after rebooting I was asked by windows firewall if it could trust google, I chose trust,  Ran chrome and nothing I nothing had changed.

Comment: @KERRmit_the_FROG Have you tried 1/ A different browser? 2/ reinstalling Chrome? 3/ Running Chrome with extensions disabled? 4/ Running Chrome with a new profile?

Comment: Yeah, none of my browsers work.